# gitosis installed ,but can not clone on other client

Tags: git, gitosis

the server show init ok
[image: the server]

but the client error 
[image: the cmd capture]

```
fatal: 'gitosis-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

use the private key can connect the server by ssh
                                                                                                                                              Please make sure you have the correct access rights
                                                                                                                                                                                                    and the repository exists.

what's wrong!!~

Answer (score 0):

git clone git@domain:/home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git

must use the  full path

Answer (score 0):

You should **never use the full path** (either with the [old obsolete gitosis, or the more recent up-to-date gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309))

Using the full path defeat the ACL (Access Control Level) put in place by gitosis/gitolite (as illustrated in "[Gitosis on Ubuntu can only find repositories in the git->repositories symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3500061/6309)", and that is the [same for gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/emergencies.html#bypass)).

See "[Git on the Server - Gitosis](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Gitosis)" (if you really *must* use gitosis): if ~git/.ssh/authgorized_key does contains the public key of the git account, and if you are using those credentials (public/private key of the git account from your client), `git@server:gitosis-admin.git` should work.